What is the correct type for $event when using (blur) in Angular
<input type="text" (blur)="onBlur($event)" />

export class AngularComponent {
  public onBlur(event: any) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    // Do other things...
  }
}

In the above code, what is the correct typescript type for event?
I would like to avoid using any here.

You can use Event for the blur, which will not have a value property in the type, for that we can cast the target to HTMLInputElement.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <input type="text" (blur)="onBlur($event)" />
  `,
})
export class App {
  public onBlur(event: Event) {
    const value = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    alert(value);
    // Do other things...
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

After doing a little digging, I found the correct type is FocusEvent which extends Event
Also, having to cast the event target to HTMLInputElement is exactly what I needed for my value property. Thank you for your quick answer!!

Sorry. it wouldn't let me check it until i waited some time. Stack overflow is kinda goofy sometimes. o_O
